# OpenCV libraries missing

Tags: c++, opencv, build, codelite

I'm failing to build a project in c++ where OpenCV is used. Here is what I got:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -leigen
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lhighgui
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcore
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -leigen
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lhighgui
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcore
```

But there are only libraries like "-lopencv_core" available nowadays.
Is there any options how to fix this?
I'm using Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

How did you install your distribution of OpenCV. The typical way of installing OpenCV is to download git repo and build it yourself.

Comment: This was exactly what I did. Maybe I somehow got an older version. I'll try to reinstall it.